# Default value of dropdown JQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, disabled-input

Two dropdowns with values 1,2 and 3 each. 3 from 1st disables the second dropdown and new option added in 2nd(new value, selected and desable). I need such option like added in the function below to be by default in the 2nd dropdown too. Thanks for the help! Here is my code:

```
<select name="first" id="first_dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second_dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and here is the function to add or remove such option while clicking on 1st dropdown:

```
  $('#first_dropdown').change(function(e){
        if($(this).val() == "3"){
            $("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',true) && $("#second_dropdown").prepend('<option value=0 class = "prepended_options" selected></option>');
        }
        else $("#appusage_dropdown").prop('disabled',false) && $(".prepended_options").remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
$('#first_dropdown').change(function(e){
        if($(this).val() == "3"){
             $("#second_dropdown").prepend('<option value="0" class="prepended_options" selected>0</option>');
             $("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {$("#second_dropdown").prop('disabled',false); $(".prepended_options").remove();}
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="first" id="first_dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second_dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It doesn`t. Maybe my explanation wasn`t so good enough. Almost what I`m trying to achieve, but by default value of the second dropdown to be the desabled '0' and '3' of the first dropwdown.

Comment: You should update your question then with a bit more clarifications. I don't get what you're trying to do